# Python 3.6.2 lazy initialization of two dimensional list

Tags: python, python-3.x

can someone explain this, I understand that some sort of lazy initialization is taking place, but unable to find any documentation/support for the same.

```
a = [[0]*3]*3
a[0][0] = 1
print(a)
```

output:

> > [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]

Comment: It's only one google search away :)

Comment: aah I knew it, but I am not able to get the right word to google it.

Comment: This isn't related to lazy initialization at all, as far as I can tell